# Solidity - What version of the contract do I deploy?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am currently learning Solidity and I have made my first BSC test contract with no errors. I have compiled my contract successfully and I am now in the deployment section of Remix.

There is a drop down menu named "contract" and within there, there are the following options:

- test.sol...ApproveAndCallFallback
- test.sol...BEP20Interface
- test.sol...Owned
- test.sol...SafeMath
- test.sol...TokenBEP20
- test.sol...

I am a bit confused as to which I actually deploy for my contract as there are multiple options. Could someone please point me in the right direction for descriptions of these options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the contract selectbox, you select the **main contract** that you want to deploy.

Most likely you have written the `TokenBEP20` token and it's going to be the `TokenBEP20`, but it all depends on your context.